# Xtext Access grammar elements from other grammar

Tags: xtext

I'm starting to find xText and I found something that I don't know how to solve.

I have 2 grammars
A.xtext

```
Domain:
    'domain' name=ID
    '{'
    (instances+=Instance)*
    '}'
Instance:
    'instance' name=ID
```

B.xText

```
import "http://somewhere/languages/A" as A

MyCommand:
    DomainCommand | InstanceCommand 
;

DomainCommand:
    'domain'
    domain=[A::Domain]
;

InstanceCommand:
    'instance'
    instance=[A::Instance]
;
```

SomeFile.A

```
domain A {
  instance X
  instance Y
}
```

SomeFile.B

```
domain A
instance A.X
```

When I'm writting my text file in my B Grammar I can access the Domain values defined in some file.A but I don't know what's the best way to access the Instance X and to make sure is from the domain A.

Comment: how did you implement scoping? or is this a question on how to implement scoping. or about instance=[A::Instance] not allowing A.X cause it gives an parse error

Comment: I haven't implemented yet. When I saw you comment I started looking into the documentation of scoping and I think that's my problem. I need to investigate more. Thanks for the help